# Why sdcard legacy getCanonicalPath not emulated/0 in Android 4.2 OS?

Tags: android, sd-card

run adb shell, look for the legacy link to /mnt/shell/emulated/0
But getCanonicalPath can't get /mnt/shell/emulated/0?

shell@android:/storage/emulated $ ls -l
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2012-12-07 12:01 legacy -> /mnt/shell/emulated/0

```
File file = new File("/storage/emulated/legacy");
String pachString = null;
try {
    pachString = file.getCanonicalPath();
        // prints /storage/emulated/legacy
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**shell@android:**`/mnt $ ls -l /mnt/`

```
ls -l /mnt/ 
drwxr-xr-x root     system            2013-03-13 16:31 asec 
drwxr-xr-x root     system            2013-03-13 16:31 obb 
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2013-03-13 16:31 sdcard -> /storage/emulated/legacy 
drwx------ root     root              2013-03-13 16:31 secure 
drwx------ shell    shell             2013-03-13 16:31 shell
```

`'/mnt/shell'` directory is accepted **shell** only.

So apps cannot `read /mnt/shell`.

Comment: the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission is now required to access the SD Card