# Symbolic link property of path "/storage/emulated/legacy"

Tags: android

I am very curious about the symbolic link of path "/storage/emulated/legacy" in Android 4.2.2

/storage/emulated/legacy is truely a symbolic link, but I can not identify is use following code

```
 public static boolean isSymbolicLink(File file) throws IOException
{
    if (file == null) throw new NullPointerException("File must not be null");
    File canon;
    String path = file.getAbsolutePath();
    if (file.getParent() == null)
    {
        canon = file;
    }
    else
    {
        File canonDir = file.getParentFile().getCanonicalFile();
        canon = new File(canonDir, file.getName());
    }
    return !canon.getCanonicalPath().equals(canon.getAbsoluteP());
}
```

Even I use lstat function in c doesn't work.

This is the result from HTC One with Android 4.2.2

$ adb shell ls -l /storage/emulated/

lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2013-08-15 12:11 legacy -> /mnt/shell/emulated/0

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you solved it? I have same problem

Comment: This sounds like the same problem answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/15402327/306864

Comment: No, I make a work around, this problem related to the multiple user mechanism.